# How to access the public data from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Analytics and Amazon. I found some data set that is public on AWS S3. I downloaded the s3fox toll but unable to use it. What are the other  means to download this data? I dont want to use a EC2 instance or Hadoop. I simply want to download these text files and run in R.

I want to download following file:
s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690169105/textData-00112

Regards
Baba

Answer (score 2):

You can access it using the following url:

http://aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690169105/textData-00112

Answer (score 0):

You can download using link mentioned by imiperalix and run below line to load data in the form of table.

textdata = read.table("{path}textData-00112");

Comment: Hi Satish ,thank you for further step. I tried this and ended up finding only 1 line i.e. "V1 1  SEQ\006\031org.apache.hadoop.io.Text \031org.apache.hadoop.io.Text\001\001'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec". I am absolutely lost here. I converted the file to .csv format and opened it to find around 250000 rows of Corrupt data. Is it I can do something  more on this?